# Comparing two files and writing mismatched rows along with mismatched columns

Tags: linux, shell

I got a usecase where I need to compare two files wrt to each columns and write the corresponding difference in another file along with some identification showing mismatched columns. For example:

```
File 1

1|piyush|bangalore|dev
1|piyush|bangalore|QA
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev
3|rohit|delhi|QA

File 2

1|piyush|bangalore|QA
1|piyush|bangalore|QA
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev
3|rohit|bangalore|dev
```

The output file must look somewhat like.

```
File 1
1|piyush|bangalore|**dev**
File 2 
1|piyush|bangalore|**QA**
File 1
3|rohit|**delhi**|**QA**
File 2
3|rohit|**bangalore**|**dev**
```

I want to achieve something like this where i can see the mismatched columns as well. 
I have tried `diff File1 File2 > Diff_File`

But this is giving me only the mismatched records or rows. I am not getting any way to point the mismatched columns as well. Please help me out if its possible to do is using shell script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `paste` to merge two files to get `1|piyush|bangalore|dev|1|piyush|bangalore|QA` then compare fields from first file (from `$1` to `$(NF/2)`) with fields from second file using `awk`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should get you in the ballpark:

```
paste -d"|" file1 file2 | awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=(NF/2);++i){if($i!=$(i+(NF/2))){print "row "NR", column"i" mismatched"}}}'
```

We are using `paste` to join the two files together, row by row and sticking a pipe between the pasted lines.

Then we pipe that to awk which

1. splits the records by pipe delimiter `-F"|"`
2. Loops through fields 1-4 for each record `for(i=1;i<=(NF/2);++i)`
3. Tests that field against the field 4 fields `(NF/2)` after it (from the second file) `if($i!=$(i+(NF/2)))`
4. Prints out the row and column that was found to be different  `{print "row "NR", column"i" mismatched"}`

You could add to that last bit to include the mismatched values:

```
{print "row "NR", column"i" mismatched. Value1: "$i", Value2: "$(i+(NF/2))}
```

Or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. But as of now i am using `dwdiff` linux utility to achieve my requirement where i am getting the mismatched columns. Below are the output which might be useful for someone.

### data1

```
1|piyush|bangalore|dev 
1|piyush|bangalore|QA 
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev 
3|rohit|delhi|QA
```

### data2

```
1|piyush|bangalore|QA 
1|piyush|bangalore|QA 
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev 
3|rohit|bangalore|dev
```

**solution.**

```
 $ dwdiff -d '|' data1 data2
```

**output**

```
1|piyush|bangalore|[-dev-]{+QA+} 
1|piyush|bangalore|QA 
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev 
3|rohit|[-delhi-]{+bangalore+}|[-QA-]{+dev+}
```